# How can I get a HTML button reference in IE's DOM from VBA when it lacks an id=""?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to use VBA macro to automatically log in on a website and I'm struggling to find a way how to click "Log on" button.

The button code:

```
<div class="GPSV45OBMKD   GPSV45OBJLD" style="line-height: 20px;">Log on</div>
```

Already tried a lot of solutions posted by other users here, yet non of them worked.

Here's the code:

```
Sub test()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "https://login.transporeon.com/login/"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate my_url

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With


ie.document.getElementById("emailForm_email-input").Value = "admin"
ie.document.getElementById("emailForm_password-input").Value = "54321haha"

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume those classes are dynamic and use instead the relationship of type for child divs and the id of the parent

```
ie.document.querySelector("#emailForm_submit div div").click
```

If they are not dynamic you can use one of the compound classes for the element

```
ie.document.querySelector(".GPSV45OBJLD").click
```

Comment: You sir are a legend.That worked like a charm. Thank you :)